# Angular.js targeting ng-class for dom manipulation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive for mobile navigation which toggles a `<ul>` on click.

The directive works well; however, when I use a class, but I am no longer able to target the class with jquery when switched to ng-class.

Here is my template.

```
<ul ng-repeat="list in englishList">

<a ng-class="{{list.title}}Hide" mobile-search-slide href="/about"><li><p>{{list.title}}</p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li></a>

<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="hideAbout">           
<div ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in searchData | aboutFilter:'abo'">

 <div ng-repeat="result in value" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
   <a ng-href="{{value.title}}/{{result.shortname}}">
   <li><p>{{result.title}}</p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li>

   </a>
   </div>  
</div> 
</li>
</ul>

 </ul>
```

This line is has the class, which I'd like to target:

```
<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="hideAbout">
```

Here is the mobile-search-slide directive:

```
app.directive('mobileSearchSlide', function(){
return{
  restrict: "A",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.click(function(){

        $('.hideAbout').slideToggle();

        console.log(element);
      });

    }
}
});
```

I plan on using ng-class as `<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="hide{{list.title}}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hideAbout` is class name, you can just use `class="hideAbout"`

In terms of ng-class:

```
<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="{'className'  : expression}">
```

It takes the classname and an expression.

So your syntax is not proper, So ng-class is failing to add the classname.

Else just use `ng-class="'hideAbout'"` here `hideAbout` is within quotes, so it will be considered as string.

> Updated:

`<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="hide{{list.title}}">` it should be like below:

```
<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="'hide ' +list.title">
```

or

```
<ul id="hideMe" class="hide {{list.title}}">
```

> DEMO

```css
ul.hide.s4 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="hideMe" ng-class="'hide ' +'s'+4">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added to my question. I plan on using interpolation in the classname

Answer (score 1):

`ng-class` expects an expression as the parameter value. Just use `'hideAbout'` like you did with `ng-class-odd` in this line:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in value" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
```